# Decode/Match Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Please help me decode this regular expression, I am new to this topic and got completely lost while trying to analyse which are valid inputs for it.

We are working on existing application where this pattern is used for password validations. While analysing the code, I am stuck to identify valid inputs for this field.
Its java application.

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[@&*~!#$%]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]{15}$
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that defines the set of allowed characters
- The groups starting with `(?=` are [positive lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), they ensure a certain condition.

So your regex is:

```
^                                             # Matches the start of the string                                             
    (?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[a-z]){2})      # ensures two lowercase letters somewhere in the whole string
    (?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[A-Z]){2})      # ensures two uppercase letters somewhere in the whole string
    (?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[@&*~!#$%]){2}) # ensures two characters out of [@&*~!#$%] somewhere in the whole string
    (?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*\d){2})         # ensure two digits somewhere in the whole string
    [a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]{15}                   # Matches exactly 15 character out of the set
$                                             # Matches the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will test a string wich length is 15 character and it contains at least:

- 2 lower case letter : `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[a-z]){2})`
- 2 upper case letter : `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[A-Z]){2})`
- 2 of `@&*~!#$%` character : `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[@&*~!#$%]){2})`
- 2 digit : `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*\d){2})`

It should be reduce as:

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[@&*~!#$%]){2})(?=(?:.*\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]{15}$
```

Answer (score 0):

First, shoot whoever wrote this.

Second, the best approach is to add newlines and comments to break up the regex into smaller parts.

```
  ^           // start of string
  (?=         // lookaround assertion
      (?:     // non-capturing group
          [a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[a-z]
      )
      {2}
  )
  (?=        // lookaround assertion
      (?:    // non-capturing group
          [a-zA-Z0-9@&*~!#$%]*[A-Z]
      )
      {2}    // exactly twice
  )
  <snip...>
  $          // end of string
```

Keep adding newlines, indents and comments, and you'll get to a full picture of the pattern.